# I can't run my flutter existing projects, what is happening?

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I keep getting this error and I don't seem to find any help online. I am new to flutter, vscode and this whole programming world. Any help is very well appreciated. The thing is I can't run my previous projects but I actually can if I create new ones.

This is what it is printed in the debug console when I try to run my previous projects:

**FAILURE:** Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script   'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
  Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: The gradle version might be updated, you can check it in the file android/build.gradle and android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties (compare the ones in an existing and a new project).

Comment: Actually both are the same, they have https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip; thanks a lot anyways

Comment: did you update studio and flutter sdk ?

Comment: Yes, I updated both

Comment: Try running "flutter clean" first then start building the app.

Comment: Thank you very much brother, fortunately it is now working like like it should!